# Is there anyway to simulate google map on android app?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am doing the project about map navigation. Currently I work fine with the mapview with GPS and singal route directing. But I can not find anyway that, show the all possible choices on the map, like google map on web.

For example I like to search what restaurants are around my area, so I type "Restaurant" in search bar and search it, the map shold display my current position (I have done this) and also show all the possible restaurants that near my area. After that I pick up one restaurant, and the map will draw the route from my position to the restaurant (I have done this too)

I have spent many time search on internet but couldn't find any critical example explain about this, is there any tutorial I can refer to?

Should I use "webview" to directly show the google map web page on app?

I also meet other problem, I use the way below to directe my route on map, it suppose to draw the route on my app, but insted of that the phone will directly oepn google map and drawn the route on google map, am I do this wrong? Is there any better way?

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(
Uri.parse("http://maps.google.com/maps?f=d&saddr="
+GeoPointToString(fromGeoPoint)
+"&daddr="
+GeoPointToString(toGeoPoint)
+"&hl=cn")
);
startActivity(intent);
```

I am the very new beginner of android programming, hope this is not a silly question, wish you can help me. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to make an app using Google Maps, you should use the Google Maps API!

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

You should be able to download it via your SDK manager in eclipse, or manually install it.  I'm using it at work right now, but be wary that you cannot make a commercial app for navigation using these maps.

Comment: I am using the google map api, since the phone not provide the way to coding on defalut app so I need to simulate the google map to work with my porject. I just not sure how to allow it search the  all possible require locations at once, as the restaurants example I explain on top